# Passing information in shortcut to a c# .exe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a wpf c# project and I would like to pass some start up information information in the way I have seen done by other coders only by looking at their short cut

So the short cut I have seen is:

> X:\Test.exe /host=[Server Location]/**instance=0 /coid=%coid /userid=%oper**

I understand the what is being passed, but I would like to understand how the c# project takes the in the information in bold and I guess assigns it in a string etc.

I have tried to google the information but I do not know what to call the topic

Any help - even a no this can not be done would be helpful

Comment: Are you sure it's not **/coid=%coid% /userid=%oper%**?

Comment: this would be called `Command Line arguments` or `Args passing` it's here is something you can read [How to process Command line ParamspWPF](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/19/how-to-process-command-line-parameters-or-arguments-in-a-wpf-application/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Command Line Parameters Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN.

An application has an entry point, which is `public static void Main(string[] args)` in this case. The `args` parameter contains the command line parameters, split by space.

Edit: my bad, didn't know WPF was obnoxious. Take a look here: [WPF: Supporting command line arguments and file extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2008/10/27/wpf-supporting-command-line-arguments-and-file-extensions.aspx):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Args != null && e.Args.Count() > 0)
    {
        this.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] = e.Args[0];
    }

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve command line parameters into `string[]` with

```
string[] paramz = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: In this case parameters must be separated with space and `paramz[0]` will contain the executable name.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the program takes one argument at run time, converts the argument to an integer, and calculates the factorial of the number. If no arguments are supplied, the program issues a message that explains the correct usage of the program.

```
public class Functions
    {
        public static long Factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n < 0) { return -1; }    //error result - undefined
            if (n > 256) { return -2; }  //error result - input is too big

            if (n == 0) { return 1; }

            // Calculate the factorial iteratively rather than recursively:

            long tempResult = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                tempResult *= i;
            }
            return tempResult;
        }
}

class MainClass
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test if input arguments were supplied:
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: Factorial <num>");
            return 1;
        }

        try
        {
            // Convert the input arguments to numbers:
            int num = int.Parse(args[0]);

            System.Console.WriteLine("The Factorial of {0} is {1}.", num, Functions.Factorial(num));
            return 0;
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: Factorial <num>");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be `The Factorial of 3 is 6.` And the usage of this application is like `Factorial.exe <num>`